# optimization of mysql select (bad performance)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

I have 3 tables:

t1 approx 500.000rows
t2 1.600rows
t3 50.000rows

My SQL query takes (around) 15sec to display results in phpmyadmin.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
      SELECT NULL AS post_subject, t1.id_rec, t1.name, t1.id_cat, t1.date_of_record
      FROM records AS t1
       INNER JOIN categories AS t3 ON t1.id_cat = t3.id_cat AND t3.private =0
     UNION 
      SELECT post_subject, NULL , NULL , NULL , post_time
      FROM posts
     ORDER BY date_of_record DESC 
     LIMIT 10
    ) a
```

And indexes are:

```
records (t1):
 id_rec = PRIMARY
 name = INDEX
 id_cat = INDEX

categories (t3):
 id_cat = PRIMARY

posts:
 post_subject = INDEX
```

The goal is to get 10rows which are ordered based on DATE_OF_RECORD && POST_TIME. Table of records and posts are not connected and they represent different data. I am trying to get some kind of "log" from my data... (t1&&t3),(posts).... as it goes in time...

Could you help me please with optimization?

Comment: For future reference, when you've accepted an answer the question will be styled differently wherever it appears on the site; there's no need to edit "solved" into the title. :)

Comment: ok, I am new here, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding `LIMIT 10` to the first part of the `UNION` too. And if you really only want 10, you would `LIMIT 10` to the final result:
To get the 10 latest of both groups you should only put the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` outside, but if you can live with that, it may be faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((
  SELECT NULL AS post_subject, t1.id_rec, t1.NAME, t1.id_cat, t1.date_of_record
  FROM records AS t1
  INNER JOIN categories AS t3
    ON t1.id_cat = t3.id_cat
      AND t3.private = 0
  ORDER BY date_of_record DESC LIMIT 10)      
  UNION      
  (SELECT post_subject, NULL, NULL, NULL, post_time
  FROM posts
  ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 10)
  ) a
ORDER BY date_of_record DESC LIMIT 10
```

Additionally, make sure you have indexes on posts.post_time and records.date_of_record to make this execute faster.

Comment: The 2-nd `ORDER BY` has to be `post_time DESC`. And he will need to have indexes on `records.date_of_record` and `posts.post_time`.

Comment: This gives me: #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY  :(

Comment: @FredericoRossini throw some `()`-s at it :)

Comment: (MySQL: 5.5.31, phpMyAdmin - 2.9.0.2)

Comment: @FredericoRossini. Try now with extra ()'s .

Comment: @Vatev , really - so easy :D a added some ( ) and it works... ;) thx